# textContent.Match specifics and formatting

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am currently running:

```
for (var el of document.querySelectorAll('script[if="inlineJs"]')) 

    {
      var m = el.textContent.match(/"([^"]*webId*[^"]*)"/);
      var webid = m;
        if (webid) return webid[1];
```

This returns:

```
{"cache":{"Co.context.configCtx":{"webId":"lex-orlando","locale":"en_US","version":"LIVE","page":"HomePage","secureSiteId":"4441a718647510048bfc0003ba0acbe3"},"features":{"directivePerfSwitch":true,"enable.directive.localisation":true,"enable.directive.thumbnailGallery":true,"enable.new.newstaticmap":false,"disable.forms.webId":false,"use.hydra.popup.title.override.via.url":true,"enable.directive.geoloc.enableHighAccuracy":true,"use.hydra.theme.service":true,"disable.ajax.options.contentType":false,"dealerLocator.map.use.markerClustering":true,"hydra.open.login.popup.on.cs.click":false,"hydra.consumerlogin.use.secure.cookie":true,"use.hydra.directive.vertical.thumbnailGallery.onpopup":true,"hydra.encrypt.data.to.login.service":true,"disable.dealerlocator.fix.loading":false,"use.hydra.date.formatting":true,"use.hydra.optimized.style.directive.updates":false,"hydra.click.pmp.button.on.myaccount.page":true,"use.hydra.fix.invalid.combination.of.filters":true,"disable.vsr.view.from.preference":false}},"store":{"properties":{"routePrefix":"/hydra-graph"}}}
```

I would like it to only return: lex-orlando

When I run:

```
for (var el of document.querySelectorAll('script[if="inlineJs"]')) {
    var m = el.textContent.match("webId");

    return m[0];
```

It only returns "webID"

Is there anyway to use textContent.match to return "lex-orlando"?

Bonues: What if the webID changes from prefixes from "lex" to "motp", "gmps", "motp" ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am spinning my wheels trying to figure this out.

I've also tried:

```
for (var el of document.querySelectorAll('script[if="inlineJs"]')) {
                var m = el.textContent.match(/"([^"]*webId*[^"]*)"/);
                var obj = JSON.parse(m);
                var myVar = obj.cache["Co.context.configCtx"].webId;
                window.alert("webId is " + myVar);
                return myVar;
```

But this returns a null value. I attempted changing my event listeners, but it does not help. That is why I am trying to see if it can be done through textContext.match

Comment: That looks like JSON, why aren't you using `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: I don't see how you're getting that return value. When I try it at https://regex101.com/r/5axeNb/1 it just matches `webID`

Comment: And conversely using `var myVar = obj.cache["Co.context.configCtx"].webId;` on  the parsed json shown should work. Provide a runnable example

Comment: Are there more script elements that don't match that scenario that you need to filter out?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `JSON.parse()` on the result of `el.textContent.match()`. First of all, it returns an array, not a single string. Second, that regexp will just match the `webId` property name, not the whole object.

I think you should just parse the whole `textContent`.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(el.textContent);
var webid = obj["Co.context.configCtx"].webId;
```